# Setting up different static error pages in IIS for different domains

Tags: iis, rewrite, custom-errors

I have got a single IIS website that will host multiple sites (using a CMS).
Each site has its own domain and will have its own theme, so I want the error pages (404 and 500) to be specific to each site as well.

Normally I would set up the error pages using the `httpErrors` section in the web.config, but I think that only works for a single set of error pages?

The idea I had in my head was to use the URL Rewrite module to rewrite the static file URL to my site-specific file, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/500.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

And the rewrite rules:

```
<rule name="Rewrite Error Pages - Site 1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(\d{3}).html$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite1.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}-mysite1.html" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rewrite Error Pages - Site 2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(\d{3}).html$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite2.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}-mysite2.html" />
</rule>
```

So I have a few static HTML files for each site as well:

- `404-mysite1.html`
- `500-mysite1.html`
- `404-mysite2.html`
- `500-mysite2.html`

The rewrite rules work fine when I go to `http://mysite1.com/404.html` for example, as it will rewrite it correctly and return the content of `404-site1.html`.

But when I go to a non-existing URL (e.g. `http://mysite1.com/foo`) it will return a blank page. I can see in the request trace (enabled through Failed Request Tracing in IIS) that it correctly tries to request `/404.html` (as is in my `httpErrors` section), but it won't then rewrite it to `/404-site1.html`.

Does anyone know if this is even possible? Or are there other ways to set up static HTML error pages for different domains in the same IIS site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I figured it's not possible using URL Rewrite rules, so am now using a simple `.aspx` page that will check the host name and render the correct error page content.

So I removed the URL Rewrite rules mentioned in the question, and change the `httpErrors` to this:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

And in the `404.aspx` file I do the following:

```
<%@ page trace="false" validateRequest="false" %>

<%-- set correct site name based on request domain --%>
<% string siteName = ""; %>
<% string hostName = Request.Url.Host; %>

<% if (hostName == "mysite1.com") { siteName = "mysite1"; } %>
<% if (hostName == "mysite2.com") { siteName = "mysite2"; } %>

<%-- return file content with a 404 status code --%>
<% Response.StatusCode = 404; %>
<% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteName)) { Response.WriteFile("404-" + siteName + ".html"); } %>
```

This seems to work fine for what I want it to do.